# Add watermark to images

Tags: php, .htaccess, cgi

I've searched for ages for a solution, but I can't really find the solution to fit my needs.

So here's the story. Im creating a website and I really want to add watermarks to the downloaded images.

Yesterday I was browsing in a website called 9gag. If you haven't heard this website before, its a comic based website, and I found out that when you download an image, or access an image from anywhere else except their website, there's a 'watermark/banner' at the bottom of the image.

For example take this image:
[link](http://9gag.com/gag/1841463) , notice no banner at the bottom of the image.

If you right-click, 'Copy image URL' , you get this link: [image](http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/1841463_700b.jpg) . See the banner now?

Im very confused on how they do it, and it would be great if we could use this on our websites.

Anyone with any ideas? Is it using any type of CGI?

P.S: I Wasn't sure what tags to add, So if anyone knows a better tag combination, please do edit it.

Comment: I dont know about your example , but you can do this (watermark adding) to images using PHP GD library , quite easy. Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is just a css trick. The image itself actually contains the watermark at the bottom, but the image tag is wrapped in a block that hides (overflow:hidden) the bottom 42 pixels of the image when it's being displayed in the page.

There are other things you can do that are more sophisticated (for instance, have the image served via a php script and comparing the http referer

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){die("alert('Restricted Access!');");};
$_u=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$_u=preg_replace("/(www.)/i","",strtolower($_u['host']));
$_i=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$_i=preg_replace("/(www.)/i","",strtolower($_i));
if ($_u != $_i){
   //handle this with gd or redirect
}
```

) but this will only work if someone tries to load the image from a different website or if they go to the image url... generally save-as will save the image from the browser's cache, so the css trick might be the best option you have (or a combination of these options). Fundamentally keep in mind that anything you show on the web can be captured (the code above isn't foolproof, and you can always prtsc).

Comment: Thank you very much for the blazing fast responce Ben D, I never thought that they would do that css trick.

Also i will try out the php code you gave me, thank you very much again.

Comment: Also keep in mind that - assuming your watermark is to prevent copyright infringement - with the example using the css trick, it is a trivial thing to chop off the bottom of that image with the watermark, including (as it is a predictable size) the ability to do so through a script or server side software that might be serving those images into another page. You might have a look into watermarking using an invisible watermark, or nearly so. I can't seem to find one right at the moment, but have seen one in the last couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

GD library of php will help you doing that.

1. You'll need to create a new image using [imagecreate](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreate.php) function but adding some more "space" to the original size. Example: if I have an image of 200x200 (which you can retrieve using gd functions too) you'll need to create a 200x220px image using that function
2. Fill the new image with that gray color using [imagefilledrectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) function
3. Copy the original image into the new one using [imagecopy](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopy.php)
4. Set the header's content type to image/**type** png gif etc..
5. Output to the image using [imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagepng.php) or any other function that has the format you want.

Comment: Although this is not exactly what i was looking for, this will be very helpful in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSchinis Yeah, sorry for that, I've understood the inverse of what you wanted. xD

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with JQuery Watermark:
[Jquery Watermark](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/jq/)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but i think Ben D has the best solution.
This jQuery Plugin always adds the watermark and i dont really want that, i only want it to be displayed when saved.